# How should I implement GetLastNode for TTreeNodes?

Tags: delphi

When I need to find the first node in a `TTreeView`, I call `TTreeNodes.GetFirstNode`. However, I sometimes need to locate the last node in a tree and there is no corresponding `TTreeNodes.GetLastNode` function.

I don't want to use `Items[Count-1]` since that results in the entire tree being walked with `Result := Result.GetNext`. Naturally this only matters if the tree views have a lot of nodes. I fully appreciate the virtues of virtual container controls but I am not going to switch to Virtual TreeView just yet.

So far I have come up with the following:

```
function TTreeNodes.GetLastNode: TTreeNode;
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Result := GetFirstNode;
  if not Assigned(Result) then begin
    exit;
  end;
  while True do begin
    Node := Result.GetNextSibling;
    if not Assigned(Node) then begin
      Node := Result.GetFirstChild;
      if not Assigned(Node) then begin
        exit;
      end;
    end;
    Result := Node;
  end;
end;
```

Can anyone:

1. Find a flaw in my logic?
2. Suggest improvements?

**Edit 1**

I'm reluctant to keep my own cache of the nodes. I have been doing just that until recently but have discovered some hard to track very intermittent AVs which I believe must be due to my cache getting out of synch. Clearly one solution would be to get my cache synchronisation code to work correctly but I have an aversion to caches because of the hard to track bugs that arise when you get it wrong.

Comment: @RRUZ: And what if that last visible node is a sub-node?

Comment: @NGLN I was about to post the same comment

Comment: I would think I could probably replace your tree view with virtual tree view in an hour, and it would get faster, and look better, and I would not have to worry about keeping treeNodes in sync with my model data, which is, in fact, the root of MANY subtle bugs, and so, in effect, you are already caching your model, in your treeview, or else you're using your treeview as a key element of your model. Both are problematic. (Think about threads, for example.)

Comment: @warren what about threads? also, virtual treeview is not native control which I don't like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I am not a non-Exit purist, I think that when it is doable without Exit while keeping readability intact, one might prefer that option.

So here is exactly the same code, for I don't think you can get any other way (faster) to the end node, but without Exit and slightly more compact:

```
function TTreeNodes.GetLastNode: TTreeNode;
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Node := GetFirstNode;
  Result := Node;
  if Result <> nil then
    repeat
      Result := Node;
      if Node <> nil then
        Node := Result.GetNextSibling;
      if Node = nil then
        Node := Result.GetFirstChild;
    until Node = nil;
end;
```

Comment: If you're going to use a iterative approach this looks close to optimal to me.

Comment: I've just desk checked this one more time and it gives an access violation, when the tree is empty, at `Result.getFirstChild`.

Answer (score 2):

The method I've used before is the maintain a TList using List.Add on the OnAddition event and List.Remove on the OnDeletion event (OnRemove?). You've access to List.Count-1 (or whatever you need) pretty much instantly then.

Post edit - I have to say that although this worked fine, I then grew up and moved to Virtual Tree View :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I've thought about this already (sorry, should have mentioned it) and am reluctant to maintain my own cache of nodes. I have actually been doing that until recently but have discovered hard to trace problems that I believe are due to my cache being out of synch.

Comment: It wouldn't be a cache of nodes, just a Tail entry. You would replace the old tail with the new tail any time a node is appended at the root, or to the current tail node.

Answer (score 2):

If I was to implement it, this would probably be my first draft.

```
function TTreeNodes.GetLastNode: TTreeNode;
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  function GetLastSibling(aNode : TTreeNode) : TTreeNode;
  begin
    if not Assigned(aNode) then
      EXIT(nil);
    repeat
      Result := aNode;
      aNode := Result.GetNextSibling;
    until not Assigned(aNode) ;
  end;
begin
  Node := GetFirstNode;
  if not Assigned(Node) then begin
    exit;
  end;

  repeat
    Result := GetLastSibling(Node);
    Node := Result.GetFirstChild;
  until not Assigned(Node);
end;
```

I find this slightly more readable.  It might be slightly slower though.

I'm unsure about whether or not this approach would be faster than items[Count-1], in some cases, it could be slower, as the TTreeNodes actually caches the last node accessed through the items property.

Comment: +1 I approve of the decomposition of GetLastSibling which makes the outer loop much more readable. Regarding the caching in `TTreeNodes`, it would only help if the last node accessed was the last node or the previous one. And that's not likely to be the case in my usage scenarios.